# HAProxy setting variables for logging

Tags: haproxy

### Goal

I am trying to output the full payload of the request as part of an error message, because I believe the requester is giving me a garbage payload. The original, working log was

```
  setenv TCP_LOG "%ci:%cp [%t] %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq"
  log-format "${TCP_LOG} %[var(txn.sendercompid)] %[var(txn.errormessage)] %[var(txn.sendercompid)] %[var(txn.mapped_sendercompid)]"
  tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) str("ERROR: SenderCompID not in request") unless { var(txn.sendercompid) -m found }
```

This is exactly the [standard tcp log format from HAProxy](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#8.2.2) plus some strings we care about.

I want to change the value of `txn.errormessage` to include the full request payload when it fails.

---

### What I've tried so far:

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) str("ERROR: SenderCompID not in request %[req.payload(0,0),regsub(\001,|,g)]")
```

which fails with

> > [ALERT]    (1) : config : parsing [/bitnami/haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg:44] : fetch method 'str' : expected ')' before ',0),regsub(\001,|,g)])'

and

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) req.payload(0,0)
```

which I believe logs the empty string in

> $IP:43384 [11/Jul/2023:20:05:00.748] fix_listener fix_listener/ -1/-1/0 0 PR 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 -  - -

Though I can see that I am being given a payload with

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) req.len
```

giving me

> $IP:43536 [11/Jul/2023:20:25:26.805] fix_listener fix_listener/ -1/-1/0 0 PR 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 - 206 - -
> $IP:43540 [11/Jul/2023:20:26:15.825] fix_listener fix_listener/ -1/-1/0 0 PR 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 - 206 - -
> $IP:43544 [11/Jul/2023:20:27:04.879] fix_listener fix_listener/ -1/-1/0 0 PR 1/1/0/0/0 0/0 - 206 - -

The closest I could get to working was

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) req.payload(0,0),hex unless { var(txn.sendercompid) -m found }
```

Which outputs hex, and if I pipe it into `xxd -r -p` I get a bunch of garbage with an IP address at the end.

I have [read a decent amount of the docs](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/), but the docs for [`tcp-request content set-var`](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4.2-tcp-request%20content%20set-var) (after redirecting to `http-request set-var`) only describe the expression I can use as

> <expr>      Is a standard HAProxy expression formed by a sample-fetch
> followed by some converters.

and there's no obvious section describing a standard HAProxy expression. I read through [the quoting and escaping section](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#2.2) and also didn't understand why I couldn't have a comma inside `str()`.

### Questions

1. How do I quote / format `str("ERROR: SenderCompID not in request %[req.payload(0,0),regsub(\001,|,g)]")` correctly to be able to concatenate a string with a variable?
2. Why doesn't setting `txn.errormessage` to `req.payload(0,0)` print anything in my logs?
3. What is the easiest way to print out the full payload of a request in a log statement?

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

1. See below
2. I have no idea
3. I have no idea

After bashing my head into the wall enough times, I got something that did what I wanted:

```
tcp-request content set-var(txn.errormessage) \
  req.payload(0,0),regsub(\x01,|,g),regsub(^,"ERROR: invalid FIX: <"),concat(">") \
  unless { req.payload(0,0),fix_is_valid }
```

Some things I learned along the way that might help others:

- `,` = `|` in bash, but `,` is ALSO used for delimiting arguments
- You need to wrap hardcoded strings in `str()` (unless they're already arguments in a converter, in which case you don't even need quotes)
- single quotes escape double quotes and start their own strongly-quoted string, I don't care what the docs say
- You can't nest converters and you should not try.
- `concat()` is worse than the docs lead you to believe and cannot make this line simpler
- HAProxy has `.if / .endif` top level statements (to try to avoid the trailing `unless`) but they only accept 6 predicates and none were useful to me.
- The docs say that [nonprinting characters are automatically cast into `#X` where X is the ASCII hex of your character](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#8.6), but that was not my experience and `\x01` was printed as that nonprinting character or the empty string (I was reading from `stdout` so if it would have been the actual SOH character, the terminal prints that as the empty string - regardless, it was not printed as `#01`)